# How to handle events on the main thread before next loop iteration

Tags: ios, cocoa, xamarin.ios, uikit, xamarin

I have a loop that creates more UI at each iteration. This means I can hardly use concurrency here. The whole sequence blocks the main thread for a long time since it's quite heavy. I'd like to detect the tap gestures that were done so that I can cancel the long processing if the user decides to go in another menu. What I would like is something like that:

```
while[...]:
  -Do a lot of UI-related operations
  -Force the main thread to handle gestures that were done 
   while the main thread was previously blocked
  -Continue to next iteration
```

I tried using `NSRunLoop.RunUntil` to force the "unclogging" of the event stack before going to the next iteration, but no avail. Anyways, I read that it is not a good practice since the RunLoop is not reentrant, even if I'm not exactly sure what that means. Any suggestions on how to proceed here?

Thanks,

Paul

Comment: Why not perform your calculation in a separate thread and use standard techniques for notifying about progress in the calculation? Is it important for some reason to block the main thread?

Comment: Yes, it is UI related operations that I do, so I have no choice but to do them on the main thread. I could use Core Graphics to prepare them on a background thread and then add the result on the main thread, but that would be a massive refactor that I can not afford.